# What do i need to do to make my Div Box look 3D?

Tags: html, css

What do I need to do to make my code work? 
I don't know how to make my div Box look 3D like the example that I found on this website(https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/box) ...But without animations and the front face.

```css
    .section-about {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(173, 56, 1), rgb(209, 144, 3));
      
      padding: 25rem 0;
      position: relative;
     
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      grid-area: section-about;
      padding-bottom: 25em;
    }
    .heading-secondary {
      font-size: 1rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 500;
      letter-spacing: 1rem;
      position:relative;

      word-spacing: 1.8rem;

      text-align: center;
      transition: all .2s;
      color: rgb(250, 228, 129);
      -webkit-color-clip: text;
      text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(240, 159, 37);
      z-index: 2;
    }


    .gradient-2 {
      background: linear-gradient(112.18318469755093deg, rgb(197, 148, 41) 15.888253539744033%, rgba(229, 151, 64, 1) 84.94202063708826%);
      position: absolute;
      
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    }
    .box__face--right,
    .box__face--left {
       width: 100px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: green;
       left: 100px;
       position:absolute;
    }

    .box__face--top,
    .box__face--bottom {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      top: 50px;
      position:absolute;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .scene {
    width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      perspective: 500px;
      
      margin: 40px;
    }

    .box {
       width: 200px;
      height: 300px;
      position: relative;
      
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform: translateZ(-50px);
    }

    box__face--right  { transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(150px); }
    .box__face--left   { transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(150px); }

    .box__face--top    { transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(100px); }
    .box__face--bottom { transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }

    .heading-secondary-background {
      background: rgb(43, 43, 43);
     
     
      position:absolute;
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
     
      
     
    }
```

```html
  `

    <section class="section-about">
   <div class="scene">
          <div class="box">
       <div class="heading-secondary-background">
      <div class="heading-secondary" data-text="10 Best Cities To Travel, Live And Work Remotely In Southeast Asia: Introduction">10 Best Cities To Travel, Live And Work Remotely In Southeast Asia</div>
     <div class="gradient-2"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="box__face box__face--right">Right</div>
     <div class="box_face box_face--left">Left</div>
     <div class="box_face box_face--top">Top</div>
     <div class="box_face box_face--bottom">Bottom</div>
     
       
   </div>
            </div>
    
  </section>
```

Comment: If you don't need the front face just don't put it ;) It will still be a square! (so transformations are the same). Otherwise check [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/creating-a-3d-cube-image-gallery/) by _Kushagra Gour_ on CSS-Tricks, it's very well explained.